# MySQL никак не хочет создавать таблицу

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, синтаксис

кажется не нравится синтаксис. перечитал, кажется, все справочники. посмотрел в phpmyadmin на хостинге 000webhost. должно работать. но не работает. не понимаю что ещё можно попробовать.

```
CREATE TABLE 'sensors'(
  sensorId INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sensorName varchar(255),
  sensorValue varchar(255),
  UNIQUE 'id'('sensorId')
);
```

Ububtu 18.04, MySQL 5.7

ошибка

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''sensors'(
  sensorId INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sensorName varchar(255)' at line 1

Comment: Текст ошибки приложите.

Comment: Зачем вы `UNIQUE` на автоинкремент ставите?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так правильно `CREATE TABLE sensors (sensorId INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, sensorName varchar(255), sensorValue varchar(255));`

Зачем вы заключили имя таблицы в одиночные кавычки? 
Также вы забыли `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: действительно, так заработало. с кавычками ошибка понятна. а насчёт первичного ключа не понял. я не хочу эту таблицу связывать с другими, зачем он? я просто хочу избежать повторений в столбце id.

Comment: Скажем так, каждая таблица должна иметь первичный ключ, не зависимо от того хотите вы ее связывать или нет.